# c++ How do you specify one of several overloaded functions as an argument in a template Function

Tags: c++, templates, function-templates

I want to use some predefined comparators as an argument for a template function.

A code skeleton:

```
struct Line
{ 
    double length() const;
    // some data
};

struct Square
{
    double area() const;
    // some data
};

bool customCompare(const Line& a1, const Line& a2) { return a1.length() < a2.length(); }
bool customCompare(const Square& b1, const Square& b2) { return b1.area() < b2.area(); }

template <typename Comparator>
double calculateSomething(Comparator&& tieBreaker)
{
    Line l1, l2;
    return tiebreaker(l1, l2) ? l1.length() : l2.length();
}

auto result = calculateSomething(customCompare);
```

However, my compiler (VS12 update 5) gives the following compile errors

```
error C2914: 'calculateSomething' : cannot deduce template argument as function argument is ambiguous
error C2784: 'double calculateSomething(Comparator &&)' : could not deduce template argument for 'overloaded function type' from 'overloaded function type'
```

Clearly, what I want to do is to specify the comparator more precisely, like

```
auto result = calculateSomething(customCompare(const Line&, const Line&));
```

But this is also not allowed...

how to solve this ? (I know I can resort to a lambda, but is there another way ?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify the template parameter type explicitly, like this:

```
auto result = calculateSomething<bool(const Line&,const Line&)>(customCompare);
```